# Mobile site functionality

Tags: feature-request, comments, mobile

On the main site, comment deletion is achieved by hovering over the comment, thereby displaying a "delete cross", and clicking it:

[image]

But, of course, no hovering is possible on a handheld device. My reference here stems from viewing the site on an iPod Touch, although I believe other handheld devices would have similar problems:

[image]

How about a feature that adds this capability to the mobile version of TeX.SX (or perhaps any of the Stack Exchange sites) in the form of a "delete" link (similar to what is displayed below a question/answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't offer every feature of the desktop site on the mobile version due to space constraints, so we tend to drop the less frequently used features.

You can of course switch to the full version via the footer and do it that way (then switch back). So there's a workaround.