# Why I can't log in to chat room from mobile while I can in to main site?

Tags: support, chat, mobile

I am using mobile to keep in touch with TeX.SX and friends there. While main site offers no problems, I can't enter the chat room. It seems if I use `full site` option in mobile, it works. But with a mobile, the idea of optimization of net work traffic is lost. Given that my mobile internet connection has variable bandwidth (as it is very slow some times) I don't want to use full site option.

## The question:

How do I log in to the chat room from my mobile without using  full site option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found this before as well - difficulty logging into chat, even from the full site from my laptop. The way I circumvent this issue with logging into [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) is to log into the main Stack Exchange *first*, and then going to the chat room of your choice.

1. Start out by clicking on the `chat` link at the bottom of the mobile site:

   [image]
2. You should find yourself at the chat rooms specific to TeX.SE. If not automatically logged in, click the `log in` link:

   [image]
3. This lands you on the main Stack Exchange chat log in page. Rather than being logged in automatically, or clicking on the `log in` link in the top menu bar, click on the link that says `log in via Stack Exchange`:

   [image]
4. At this stage you can select your usual log in routine (via an OpenID, say) to gain access, view and contribute in the regular chat room.

It is understandable that the mobile version of the site has [some limitations](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1989/5764). However, depending on your device, you may successfully switch to a full version of chat:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this procudure works for smartphones/tablets based on Android OS

Comment: Look ma, I'm in the screenshots! Woohoo! `:)`

Comment: Yes, I tested on android smartphone.

Comment: Tested on Samsung galaxy. Working! Yay.