# have lost "interactive" view of chat; how can i get it back?

Tags: support

while connected to the chat on my laptop the other day (macbook pro, snow leopard, firefox), the format of the chat room suddenly changed from the "usual" format, with forward/back pointers and a list of miscellaneous stuff on the right, to a very "depleted" format with only bands the full width of the screen containing just the participant id, the text, and occasional timestamps.  although i can read what's going on, i'm unable to participate, and there's nothing on the screen that gives a hint of how to change the format or even to log out.  (there *are* buttons that allow me to go to a different chat room, but that's not what i'm looking for.)

this question appeared in the "maybe your answer is here" list when i launched my present question:  [Why I can't log in to chat room from mobile while I can in to main site?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3927/579)

thinking that this seems potentially similar, i've taken a look, and tried to follow the suggestion to log out and back in again.  after quite a few random attempts, trying to click on every available button, i did manage to log out;
the only reason i'm fairly sure i succeeded is that i finally got a "log in" button that i was able to click on, and was reconnected.  however, the format hasn't changed, and the view is still "unthreaded read only".

obviously i have done something stupid.  it doesn't matter greatly at the moment, because i'm only 15 minutes from my office, where this problem hasn't arisen.  but in several weeks, i'll be a thousand miles away with only my laptop, and i really don't want to be locked out of the chat.

can someone provide step-by-step instructions for getting out of this straitjacket?

Comment: Can you provide a view of what this looks like? Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: That usually happens when the CSS file is corrupted. Ctrl+F5 maybe helps to load from scracth instead of cached version?

Comment: sounds like you selected the mobile site. down at the bottom should be a menu and you can select full site

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- tried that.  didn't work.  all it did was effectively remove the "menu" and "send" buttons and the type-in box, and change the assortment of buttons at the top (but not to anything useful).

Comment: @Werner -- david carlisle has kindly provided a screen shot of something *almost* the same, in chat (at about 8:30 according the timestamps that show on my view on the office workstation).  the difference between that and what i see on my laptop screen is that on my laptop, the bottom bar, with the buttons "menu" and "send" and the type-in box, is absent.  it's *really* "read only".

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20682638#20682638

Comment: @percusse -- Ctrl+F5 tries to brighten the screen. Cmd+F5 launches a (useless) voice-over program.  i will have to try clearing the cache separately, but that will take a while, since i have some links in the cache that i don't want to lose -- because i have lost the passwords to those sites, and have to go through administrative hoops to get new ones.

Comment: @barbarabeeton After seeing the screenshot I'm definitely wrong about the CSS possibility. That is certainly a page with a CSS

Comment: @percusse -- okay, no problem.  thanks for trying to help though.